# How to avoid validation on hidden fields in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

**How would i Not validate hidden fields when the container has `hidden: true` but not the actual field**

I did the following override as an attempt to solve this problem, it worked, tried my best not to affect the normal flow of validation so the code does not look good.

```
/* traverse up and look for a hidden Parent/Ancestor */
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
    isParentHidden: function () {
        return this.up('[hidden=true]');
    }
});

/* override isValid basic method to consider skipValidateWhenHidden property, 
when skipValidateWhenHidden is set to true code should check if the elementor it's Parent/Ancestors is hidden */
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
    isValid: function () {      
        var me = this,
            disabled = me.disabled,
            isHidden = me.isHidden(),
            skipValidateWhenHidden = !!me.skipValidateWhenHidden,
            validate = me.forceValidation || !disabled,
            isValid = validate ? me.validateValue(me.processRawValue(me.getRawValue())) : disabled;

        if (isValid || !skipValidateWhenHidden) {
        return isValid;
        }

        if (skipValidateWhenHidden) {
            isHidden = isHidden ? true : me.isParentHidden();
            if (isHidden) {
                return skipValidateWhenHidden;
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
});
```

and eventually i'll be able to do the following, which is set the property to true on the field so if its not visible for the user, it will survive the validation

```
 {
      itemId: 'City',
      cls: 'AddressCity',
      xtype: 'textfield',
      emptyText: emptyCityText,
      skipValidateWhenHidden: true,
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to disable the fields when the parent is hidden. As the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-isValid) says, disabled fields are automatically considered valid.

Then you can handle this on a per-view basis and implement listeners on the parent show/hide events to enable/disable form fields within it.

Comment: i already considered that i know that disabling the buttons would make them skip validation, but for my case i'm showing and hiding the parent's parent dynamically and managing the Field states while doing the show and hide is not easier

Comment: For clarity's sake I put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpastore84/ep6upg0f/) to illustrate the idea. In the simple listener that I implemented on the `fieldcontainer` I query for all the `field` components beneath the container. So in theory no matter how the parent is shown or hidden, the fields are automatically disabled/enabled for you. Just thought I'd put something together to see if that helps you any.

Comment: Thanks man that looks like a valid solution to many but not all cases, again in case of one more level of nesting it won't work, for example in my case i have an address class, and a level under i have CityStateZip Class. i know it should not be that nested, but considering the logic and the amount of code that comes with these classes i makes sense. anyway thank you for the suggestion. One of my colleagues made the same thing in mixins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and ended up doing this:

```
if (!me.isFormValid(form)) {
    ...
}

isFormValid: function (form) {
    var isValid = true,
        fields = form.getForm().getFields();

    fields.each(function (field) {
        if (!field.isHidden || (field.isHidden && !field.isHidden())) {
            isValid = isValid && field.isValid();
        }
    });

    return isValid;
},
```